# How to install iOS software update for macOS when it fails to install automatically?

Tags: macos, ipad, install

When I plug in my 2018-generation iPad Pro running iPadOS 15.7 to my 2018-generation iMac running macOS 10.15.7, I get a prompt for installing a software update to let the Mac communicate with the iPad:

[image]

If I click **Install**, it proceeds to download the software and start the installation, but then it fails with this message:

[image]

On my macOS + iPad combination, this is a repeatable problem, and I have not been able to install whatever update it is trying to install in this manner. I've run the regular macOS software update, rebooted the iPad and Mac, but never has this software installation succeeded.

**Is there an alternative way to install whatever software it is trying to install?** Is there a separately downloadable package or disk image or *something* that will let me get this update but not using this automated method?

Comment: Is this an admin account?

Comment: On the Mac, yes.